# VBA/Excel - querying Apache Drill

Tags: vba, apache, excel, apache-drill

I trying to built a macro for querying the Apache Drill. I cannot get it working.

I tried two ways.

First using the `QueryTables.Add`. It keeps adding the results so that is not updating the results but only shifts the old results to the right and inserts new set in A1.

**Q**: how to make the query delete old results and place new ones in the same place?

Second try using the `ADODB.Recordset`. The connection doesn't work

Error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

**Q**: can `ADODB.Connection`, `ADODB.Recordset` be used for querying data from Appachi Drill?

**First attempt**

```
Sub S3Download()

Dim sConn As String
Dim oQt As QueryTable
Dim sSql As String

sConn = "ODBC;DSN=MapR Drill;"
sSql = "SQL statement"
Set oQt = Sheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=sConn,_
         Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("A1"), SQL:=sSql)

        With oQt
            .Name = "Query1"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = False
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        End With
End Sub
```

**Second attempt**

```
Sub S3_download()

Dim oCn As ADODB.Connection
Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnString As String
Dim SQL As String


Dim qt As QueryTable
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate

ConnString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};DSN=MapR Drill;"
Set oCn = New ADODB.Connection
oCn.ConnectionString = ConnString
oCn.Open

SQL = "SQL statement"

Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
oRS.Source = SQL
oRS.ActiveConnection = oCn
oRS.Open

Set qt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcQuery, Source:=oRS, _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1")).QueryTable

qt.Refresh

If oRS.State <> adStateClosed Then
oRS.Close
End If

If Not oRS Is Nothing Then Set oRS = Nothing
If Not oCn Is Nothing Then Set oCn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the first way (macro clears the "Data" sheet first and then adds the results from the query in the desired place)

```
Sub S3Download()

    Dim sConn As String
    Dim oQt As QueryTable
    Dim sSql As String


    'removing old query data

    Sheets("Data").Cells.ClearContents

    For Each qTable In Sheets("Data").QueryTables
                qTable.Delete
    Next qTable



    sConn = "ODBC;DSN=MapR Drill;"
    sSql = "SQL statement"
    Set oQt = Sheets("Data").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=sConn,_
             Destination:=Sheets("Data").Range("A1"), SQL:=sSql)

            With oQt
                .Name = "Query1"
                .FieldNames = True
                .RowNumbers = False
                .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                .PreserveFormatting = True
                .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                .BackgroundQuery = True
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                .SavePassword = False
                .SaveData = True
                .AdjustColumnWidth = False
                .RefreshPeriod = 0
                .PreserveColumnInfo = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
                .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            End With
    End Sub
```